# turning java program into standalone application

Tags: java, computer-science

I am trying to convert my java program, TextFileAnalyzer, to a standalone application. I am not sure how to go about this I have done research and did not find anything helpful. If someone could get me in the right direction that would be awesome! Thanks.. Here is my program for reference:

Comment: Looking at your post I would say your program stands already _very_ alone indeed ...

Comment: Step 1: Delete this question, because it's too broad for this site. Step 2: Choose a target language (C++ and C# could be good candidates). Step 3: Go through your Java program line by line, and translate from Java to your target language using online resources for your target language. Step 4: Come back when you have a *specific* bit of code, in your target language, that doesn't work, and open a question about that *specific* bit of code - explain your expected and observed results and include your code.

Comment: Java is not kooked, it's brewed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what platform(s) you are targeting, or if you need to ship a complete executable. But, there are a few cross-platform Java wrappers. A common one is [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).